# Rename urls using htaccess in BlueHost

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bluehost

I want to change/rename urls in my website. For now I'm just removing `.html` in url like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpage.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I want to change urls. For example: `index.html -> home`, `aboutus.html -> about-us` etc. I tried changing but I got server client error 500:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpage.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.html /home [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^aboutus\.html /about-us [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^index\.html /home [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^aboutus\.html /about-us [NC,L]
> ```

It's not clear why you would get a 500 error here, unless you had combined these rules with the former rule that handled `.html` extensionless URLs (this would have caused a rewrite-loop, ie. 500 error).

However, the arguments you are passing to the `RewriteRule` directives are the wrong way round. You should be rewriting *from* `/home` to `/index.html` instead. The first argument matches the requested URL. The second argument (the *substitution* string) represents the URL (or file-path) you are rewriting to.

Your directives should be like this instead:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpage.html

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^home$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ aboutus.html [L]
```

The slash prefix on the substitution string (second argument) is not required.

You should be linking to URLs of the form `/home` and `/about-us` in your HTML source and mod_rewrite internally rewrites these requests to the corresponding file that actually handles the request.